# make a page break in the grouping of the ids

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want it to always change pages when it changes id in foreach to separate the pages when printing.

I have the following code:

```js
var data = [
   {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "562", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "562",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
];

var data1 = [
   {Id_Linha: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "camisola", },
   {Id_Linha: "562", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "calças", },,
];

var results = data.concat(data1).reduce(function(results, item) {
  var id = item.Id || item.Id_Linha; // Use the "Id" property if it exists, otherwise use the "Id_Linha" property
  (results[id] = results[id] || []).push(item);
  return results;
}, {});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {
  var linha = ``;
  Object.keys(results).forEach(id => {
    linha += `<div class="teste">
              <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" border="1">
              
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Nº Recibo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Data de Vencimento</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>                              
               <tbody>`;
    results[id].forEach(item => {
      var idValue = item.Id || item.Id_Linha; // Use the "Id" property if it exists, otherwise use the "Id_Linha" property
      var valor = item.valor;
      var descricao = item.Descricao;
      linha += `<tr>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${idValue}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${valor}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${descricao}</td>
                 </tr>`;
    })
    linha += `</tbody></table></div>`;
  });
  $('#minhaDiv3').show();
  $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
});
  
  
  
  document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThis")); 
}

function printElement(elem) {

    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    
    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    console.log($printSection);
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();

}
```

```css
@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none !important;
  }

}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden !important;
  }
  
  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible !important;
  }
  #printSection {
    position:absolute !important;
    left:0 !important;
    top:0 !important;
    
  }
  .teste{ page-break-after: always;}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" href="s3" data-element="#minhaDiv3">Teste</button>

<section id="s3">
  <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv3">
    <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="btnPrint" style="text-align:right;">Print</button>

      <div id="printThis">
        <div class="row pagmfalta">

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The code creates the pages but the tables are all on the first page. I wanted the first table to appear on the first page, the second table on the second page, and so on.

I'm grouping the ids when returning the tables, maybe the solution would be to make a page break whenever the id changes, but I don't see how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the media print, the 100vh uses 100% of the device hight, i added some padding to make it look better, but the padding adds to the height, so i had to calculate 15px less

```
    .teste {
      height: calc(100vh - 15px);
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
```